# Submit same form to multiple locations without Javascript

Tags: php, html

Having looked at various similar questions, both on SO and elsewhere, I have a horrible feeling what I want to do is impossible, but here goes.

I have a page that is a table of text input rows. The user enters information on each row, and submits the data to a separate file, which creates a PDF.

The problem is that I need the user to be able to add rows to the table at will, since the amount of data can vary.

*[Before you go there, I need to point out that I cannot use Javascript for any of this - I know it is easy to do in JS but the page needs to be accessible.]*

Here is a very simplified version I just cobbled together to (hopefully) illustrate the point:

```
<?php 
  if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'add_rows')) {
    $howmanyrows = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'howmanyrows', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    //get all the data from table and put it in an array, 
    //then add 5 (or however many) new rows to said array.
  }
  else if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'send_data')) {
    //get table data, add to session and redirect to other page with a header()
  }
 ?>
<html>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <table>
      <?php //table rows added using an array of data 
        foreach ($data as $d): ?>
          <tr><td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $d; ?>"></td></tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>

    </table>
    <input type="text" name="howmanyrows" value="5">
    <input type="submit" name="add_rows">

    <input type="submit" name="send_data">

  </form>
...
</html>
```

As you can see, at the moment I have a clunky setup where there is just one form that encompasses the entire page, and submits the page to itself. Depending on the button that was clicked, a new row is added or the data is submitted to the PDF-creation page.

This is not ideal, for so many reasons. What I really want to be able to do is have two separate forms, or nested forms. But the former won't allow the input values to be submitted to both, and the latter is apparently bad form (no pun intended) and doesn't work.

Is it at all possible to make this do what I want it to do? Any suggestions for a different way to go about it?

Comment: Is the "No Javascript because of accessibility" a rule you've been set by your client (or lecturer etc), or something you are trying to avoid because of your target audience. Assuming you're targetting a vision impaired person, the general rule is you can change the form/layout so long as you tell the user - telling the user is the hard part. So if not an absolute "must" I suggest you check with your target clients if a javascript approach is possible with apprpriate notification.

Comment: What do you mean by "two separate forms"? Two separate forms on the same page or two separate pages with 1 form each?

Comment: If not using JavaScript is an absolute necessity, what is wrong with the way you have the code set up?

Comment: to be honest, I just thought it was good practice to make the thing work without having any js, and using js later to make it more dynamic. now that you mention it, I am almost certain my target audience will all have js enabled. it's a utility for teachers at junior high schools in my city, and all the city computers are Vista/IE8. I guess... I don't need an answer, then? D'oh.

Comment: The thing about the way the code is set up is it's bizarre and clunky. This question stemmed from the fact I wanted the PDF to be created in a new window, which is impossible with the current setup, but would of course be easy in JS. Thanks, guys/girls.

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer - but the real accepted answer should be the first comment then - ask your audience. Anyone on the web, vision impaired or otherwise, will be now used to javascript: your challenge is to make it as easy as possible for them. Good javascript, with notifications, will be better than reloading the form and asking them to hop down to the new field (and if you don't believe me, you should try one of the screen readers like VoiceOver, NVDM, Jaws or Window Eyes). The majority of struggling users will probably be low vision if they are struggling. Don't forget them :)

Comment: Yeah, I've only recently started trying to make things accessible since I found the WAI guidelines. It's quite a mountain of information to process....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the best non-javascript solution - certainly hte way I'd run with it.

One thing to make it easier is that you can use multiple inputs with the same name:

```
<input name="tablerow[]" type="text" value="A" />
<input name="tablerow[]" type="text" value="B" />
<input name="tablerow[]" type="text" value="C" />
```

And these come through the $_POST['tablerow'] as an array. The length of the array is the number of fields. Then add additional fields to that.

---

For accessibility, you should add a link at the top that allows the user to hop directly to the first "new" field - otherwise they need to tab through the entire form to get to the new field. (See my comment above about if JS is really unavoidable as you and they can avoid this scenario!)

Comment: Glad to know I wasn't completely crazy. And thanks for the array tip; I'd forgotten that was possible.